# Why does Popen.poll() return a return code of None even though the sub-process has completed?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I have some Python code that runs on Windows that spawns a subprocess and waits for it to complete. The subprocess isn't well behaved so the script makes a non-blocking spawn call and watches the process on the side. If some timeout threshold is met it kills of the process, assuming it has gone of the rails.

In some instances, which are non-reproducible, the spawned subprocess will just disappear and the watcher routine won't pick up on this fact. It'll keep watching until the timeout threshold is passed, try to kill the subprocess and get an error, and then exit.

**What might be causing the fact that the subprocess has gone away to be undetectable to the watcher process? Why isn't the return code trapped and returned by the call to `Popen.poll()`?**

The code I use to spawn and watch the process follows:

```
import subprocess
import time

def nonblocking_subprocess_call(cmdline):
    print 'Calling: %s' % (' '.join(cmdline))
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return p


def monitor_subprocess(handle, timeout=1200):
    start_time = time.time()
    return_code = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
        return_code = handle.poll()
        if return_code == None:
            # The process is still running.
            if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
                print 'Timeout (%d seconds) exceeded -- killing process %i' % (timeout, handle.pid)
                return_code = handle.terminate()
                # give the kill command a few seconds to work
                time.sleep(5)
                if not return_code:
                    print 'Error: Failed to kill subprocess %i -- return code was: %s' % (handle.pid, str(return_code))
                # Raise an error to indicate that the process was hung up
                # and we had to kill it.
                raise RuntimeError
        else:
            print 'Process exited with return code: %i' % (return_code)
            break
    return return_code
```

What I'm seeing is that, in cases where the process has disappeared, the call to `return_code = handle.poll()` on line 15 is returning `None` instead of a return code. I know the process has gone away completely -- I can see that it is no longer there in Task Manager. And I know the process disappeared long before the timeout value was reached.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give an example of your cmdline variable? And also what kind of subprocess are you spawning?

I ran this on a test script, calling a batch file with the command:

```
ping -n 151 127.0.0.1>nul
```

- Sleep for 150 seconds

and it worked fine.

It may be that your subprocess isn't terminating correctly. Also, try changing your sleep command to something like time.sleep(2).

In the past I've found this to work better than a longer sleep (esspecially if your subprocess is another python process).

Also, I'm not sure if your script has this, but in the else: statement, you have an extra parenthesis.

```
else:
    #print 'Process exited with return code: %i' % (return_code))
    # There's an extra closing parenthesis
    print 'Process exited with return code: %i' % (return_code)
    break
```

And how come you have a global temp_cmdline being called in the join statement:

```
print 'Calling: %s' % (' '.join(temp_cmdline))
```

I'm not sure if cmdline is being parsed from a list variable temp_cmdline, or if temp_cmdline is being created from a string split on spaces. Either way, if your cmdline variable is a string, then would it make more sense to just print it?

```
print 'Calling: %s' % cmdline
```

Comment: It's a stochastic simulation command, I'm afraid I can't say much more than that. It happens about 1 in every 1000 executions and I've never been able to reproduce it reliably. The extra parenthesis and that `temp_cmdline` variable are thanks to some clean up I did before I posted, but good catch! :) `cmdline` is a list.

Comment: Ok. This is nice because the last sub processing I did was for a GUI wrapper around a predictive tool based around stochastics. Is it created in python, if so what library are you using? PyMC? Also, how long is your simulation supposed to take? Does your code need to run something else while the simulation is taking place? Because you may just be able to call the wait() command instead of polling. And if it is a python based simulation command, maybe you can use threading instead.   One more thing, have you tried reducing the sleep from 60 seconds to 2?

Comment: The third party command is C-based and I don't have the source for it. And it has a habit of hanging up, that's why the polling solution was implemented. I'll try the sleep time reduction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

poll method on subprocess objects does not seem to work too good.
I used to have same issues while i was spawning some threads to do some job.
I suggest that you use the multiprocessing module.

Comment: I'm refactoring with that solution now but was hoping there was an explanation for the wonky `Popen.poll()` behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Popen.poll doesnt work as expected if stdout is captured by something else, you can check taking out this part of the code ", stdout=subprocess.PIPE"

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar issue with a very similar setup to yours. @Ema's answer led me down the right path to solving it. I was able to get it to work by calling `communicate()` occasionally on the subprocess.  My theory is that the `PIPE` buffer gets full if your process creates too much output which triggers some bug that prevents `poll()` from setting `returncode`.

Try changing your code to something like:

```py
def monitor_subprocess(handle, timeout=1200):
    start_time = time.time()
    return_code = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
        try:
          handle.communicate(timeout=0.25)
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
          pass

        return_code = handle.returncode
        # ...
```